# Google Apps Scriptを使って，あるGoogleドライブ内のファイルの数を表示させる方法

Tags: google-apps-script

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]説明が不十分であったため，追加させていただきました。
上の画像のように，GASを使って，スプレッドシートのそれぞれの「項目」に該当する，Googleドライブ内にある，ファイルの数を「事例数」の列に反映させたいのですが，どのようにやったらいいでしょうか？Googleドライブ内のフォルダは，下の画像のように各項目ごとに分かれていて，このフォルダ内のファイル数を項目ごとに反映させたいです。
どなたか，お力添えください。

Answer (score 1):

[DriveApp.getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles) でGoogleドライブ内の全ファイルをループし、都度カウントすればファイル数が取得できると思います。
なお、「共有アイテム」「最近使用したアイテム」もカウントされるようです。
また、ファイル数が多い場合は GoogleAppsScript の制限時間内に終わらないかもしれないので、別途工夫が必要になるかと思います。

```
function myFunction() {
  var count = 0;
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    count++;
    var file = files.next();
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(count);
}
```